# IIS7 URL rewrite rules makes friendly url recursive

Tags: friendly-url, url-rewrite-module

I have a site done in asp and url rewritten rules from a db provider. I works fine but I have an annoying issue I've not been able to solve correctly.
The rewritten rules work as follows:

```
www.mydomain.com/default.asp --> www.mydomain.com/lang
www.mydomain.com/content.asp?id=1 --> www.mydomain.com/lang/category-title
www.mydomain.com/content.asp?id=1&ref=2 --> www.mydomain.com/lang/category-title/content-title
```

The rules are:

```
    <rules>
    <clear />
    <rule name="dbp_Redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{DB:{R:1}?{QUERY_STRING}}" pattern="(.+)" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" logRewrittenUrl="false" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="dbp_Reverse" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{DB_rewrite:{R:1}}" pattern="(.+)" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}" logRewrittenUrl="false" />
    </rule>
</rules>
<outboundRules>
    <clear />
    <rule name="Outbounddbp_Reverse" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1" enabled="true">
        <match filterByTags="A" pattern="^(.*/)(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
            <add input="{DB_outbound:{R:2}}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="(.+)" ignoreCase="true" negate="false" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" value="{C:0}" />
    </rule>
    <preConditions>
        <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
            <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
        </preCondition>
    </preConditions>
</outboundRules>
```

The problem is that when the user gets to

```
www.mydomain.com/lang/category-title/content-title
```

page all the links rewritten in this page goes like this:

```
www.mydomain.com/lang/category-title/content-title/*lang/category-title/content-title*
```

(as you can see the "`lang/category-title/content-title`" is repeated twice)

Sure I'm missing something in the rules but I cannot see what it is.

Any help would be appreciated.